# Why isn't my label displaying all the text?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

```
public int dialog()
{
    Form prompt = new Form(); // creates form

    //dimensions
    prompt.Width = 300;
    prompt.Height = 125;

    prompt.Text = "Adding Rows"; // title

    Label amountLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 0, Text = "Enter a number from 1-50" }; // label for prompt
    amountLabel.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F);
    TextBox value = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 25, Width = prompt.Width / 2 }; // text box for prompt
    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = prompt.Width / 2 - 50, Width = 50, Top = 50 }; // ok button
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); }; // if clicked it will close

    prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation; // enter

    prompt.KeyPreview = true;
    prompt.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) prompt.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; // user presses ESC key to close
    };

    // adding the controls
    prompt.Controls.Add(value);
    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(amountLabel);
    prompt.ShowDialog();

    // returning and checking if int block
    int num;
    Int32.TryParse(value.Text, out num);
    return num;
}
```

This is the full code. The short version of the code is:

```
Label amountLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 0, Text = "Enter a number from 1-50" };
prompt.Controls.Add(amountLabel);
```

[image: My Prompt]

The problem is that it will only display up to "Enter a number". It won't display the full text for some reason. I tried shorter "E" and it worked. I even tried "Enter a number from" but it still didn't fully display.

Comment: What happens if `Label.Left = 0`?

Comment: @mattm Is that for the label Left?

Comment: Yes. Not sure if that is the solution, but seems like the first obvious troubleshoot.

Comment: @mattm Yeah I tried to align it to the text box (50) but it's still the same thing :(

Comment: @mattm Doesn't it require a casting? It's giving me an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could enable `AutoSize`, which is set to `true` by default if you create it via the designer:

```
Label amountLabel
    = new Label { AutoSize = true, Left = 50, Top = 0, Text = "Enter a number from 1-50" };
```

Comment: Well programmatically you have to write out the properties. I honestly learned all the controls codes written without the designer off of the designer. That's how I made array of textboxes or controls. "You can accept an answer in 1 second"

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the label:

```
Label amountLabel = new Label() { Left = 75, Top = 0, Width = 1000, Text = "Enter a number from 1-50" };
```

Don't make the width *that* wide, though. I just wanted to make sure the text fits without testing different values.

I was surprised that it didn't adjust the width automatically.

Comment: How big is the Width by default without having to set it?

Comment: I think it's 100. That's what it says on my machine when I use `MessageBox.Show(amountLabel.Width.ToString());`

Comment: Yeah it's 100. But how do we know how big a label is anyways? Mine is only 24 characters "Enter a number"

Comment: I think trial and error would be the easiest way to figure out the right width.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Label's AutoSize property to true.

```
Label amountLabel = new Label() { AutoSize=true, Left = 50, Top = 0, Text = "Enter a number from 1-50" };
```