# C# Wierd String behavior after converting it from a byte[]. (Exif Data)

Tags: c#, image, exif

So I am working on a little program that helps you sort and view images.
I am currently trying to load the Exif Data and display it. 
The conversion and loading works, but the problem is when I am trying to concatenate the camera and the maker's name, the label only displays the first string.

EDIT:
Found the problem thanks to @Kevin Gosse

Comment: What does `enc.GetString(bytes)` return? Have you checked it contains all the data?

Comment: Yup, ofc I have.

Comment: Then the conversion code is irrelevant to the question and can be removed. Now, have you checked that `data` contains everything you need? You can set a breakpoint in Visual Studio then inspect the variable manually

Comment: Is it possible the size of the label is truncating the model name?

Comment: Is your label [wide enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225028/11683), and does your text [contain a null character (`'\0'`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29362493/11683)?

Comment: "I made a little lib for loading the Exif data" - apparently you made it wrong. We can't see it so we can't help.

Comment: @KevinGosse Yes , everything is right.
The problem is at the part where I am adding the two strings together.

Comment: @juharr Nope, the size of my label is big enough, already checked that.

Comment: @GSerg Yup is wide enough, oh would a \0 terminate every following string? Havent checked if something like that is in the string. Gona check that real quick.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @HenkHolterman I didnt post it because it isent the origin of the problem.

Comment: The `operator+(string, string)` isn't broken. The code that fills `data.manufacturer` is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Both arent broken. I checked twice. I guess the problem might be that the string is ending on a \0 maby. Not sure. But I have to check.

Comment: @KevinGosse Yup, there was a \0 at the and of the string. And WinForms doesnt display that for some reason. I ended up with removing the last char of the string and now it works ! Thank you very much!

Comment: That `'\0'` does belong in the WinAPI struct but never should have made it to your C# `.manufacturer`

Comment: @HenkHolterman True, but the Exif data that the System.Imaging lib gives you has got a '\0' at the end of every string. I guess thats just from the Camera and I didnt know that :D

Comment: No, that `\0` should be there, because it's a C string. You have to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the `String` contained a null character `\0` which caused the label to get rendered without the subsequent text. I fixed it by removing the last char of the string.   (Solution suggested by @KevinGosse in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the strings (especially the first one) does not end with a new line character. The safest way to do this is to use `TrimEnd()`.

It's also useful to extract these explicitly into separate variables, check the values for validity, and then construct the rest of the logic:

```
// data gathering & pre-processing
string makerName = data.MakerName.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
string camModel = data.CameraModel.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');

//build UI text
string labelText = makerName + " - " + camModel;

//update UI
theLabel.Text = labelText;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already fixed it thanks to @Kevin Gosse !
I am doing the data gathering and pre-processing already inside my libraray. So no need to do it twice :)


But Thanks anyways :D